# Download mixpanel data using lambda. Scaling issue

Tags: aws-lambda, mixpanel

We are getting the mixpanel data using lambda. Since our data volume is increasing, we are already using the 5gb of memory. We are thinking on pipeline scaling levels now, is there a better service that can do similar job. Because 10 gb is the limit for lambda.

Wanted to know the other service which can help us.